# ggplot: Drawing tiles / rectangles with discrete variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to draw tiles / rectangles to get the following result:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(
  a = runif(5),
  b = runif(5),
  c = runif(5),
  d = runif(5),
  case_id = 1:5
) %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -case_id)

plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(
  data = df,
  mapping = aes(
    x = name,
    y = value,
    group = case_id
  )
) + geom_point()

plot_boxes_y <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .2)
plot_boxes_x <- unique(df$name) %>% length()

for (x in 1:plot_boxes_x) {
  for (y in plot_boxes_y) {
    plot <- plot + geom_rect(
      mapping = aes_(
        xmin = x - .5,
        xmax = x + .5,
        ymin = y - .5,
        ymax = y + .5
      ),
      color = "red",
      fill = NA
    ) 
  }
}

plotly::ggplotly(plot)
```

[image: desired output]

As you can see, I currently do this by looping through coordinates and drawing each rectangle individually. The problem is, that this generates many layers which makes `plotly::ggplotly()` really slow on large datasets.

Therefore, I'm looking for a more efficient way. **Please note, that I cannot use the `panel.grid`, since I intend to visualize `z`-data by filling rectangles later on.**

My approach was to draw `geom_tile()` on top of the scatter plot:

```
# my attempt
df$z <- rep(0, nrow(df))

plot2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(
  data = df,
  mapping = aes(
    x = name,
    y = value,
    color = z,
    group = case_id
  )
) + geom_point() + geom_tile()
```

I assume that this fails because of the fact that `name` is a discrete variable? So, how can i efficiently draw tiles in addition to my scatterplot?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `geom_tile` option.  The key here creating a data frame to hold the coordinates of the grid and then specifying the aesthetics individually in each of the function calls.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(
  a = runif(5),
  b = runif(5),
  c = runif(5),
  d = runif(5),
  case_id = 1:5
) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -case_id)

df$z <- rep(0, nrow(df))

#make data frame for the grid corrdinates
grid<-data.frame(x=factor( ordered( 1:4), labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d" )),
                  y=rep(seq(0, 1, .1), each=4))

#plot using geom_tile & geom_point
plot2 <- ggplot2::ggplot() + geom_tile(data=grid, aes(x=x, y=y), fill=NA, col="red") +
   geom_point(data = df,
                 mapping = aes(
                   x = name,
                   y = value,
                   color = z,
                   group = case_id)) 

print(plot2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind them going beyond the axis

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=value)) + geom_point() + 
geom_vline(xintercept=seq(0.5,4.5,by=1)) +
geom_hline(yintercept=seq(0,2,by=.2))
```

else:

```
#make a new data frame
GRIDS = rbind(
# the vertical lines
data.frame(x=seq(0.5,4.5,by=1),xend=seq(0.5,4.5,by=1),y=0,yend=2),
# the horizontal lines
data.frame(x=0.5,xend=4.5,y=seq(0,2,by=.2),yend=seq(0,2,by=.2))
)

ggplot(df,aes(x=name,y=value)) + geom_point() +
geom_segment(data=GRIDS,aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend),col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution! @Dave2e's answer fits my case a tick better, but this surely is helpful to others too!